# What's the best way to automatically print an HTML header and bottom in php?

Tags: php, html, header

Currently I'm using:

```
PrintHeader();
/* Page code... */
PrintBottom();
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: My recommendation: Use a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Any output shouldn't be done automatically. As not every script call may return a page of text. So, you have to call page renderer manually.

So, you can make it with single call `CallTemplateRender();`
Not a much difference though

Answer (score 1):

Its best to separate your business logic and display code, I typically use a master php page with a variable that includes an inner php page. Something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    include($template_file);
</body>
</html
```

Then my logic page works like this:

```
//do processing
$set_variables;

$template_file = "inner_file.php";
include("master_template.php");
```

Of course its a little more involved than that but all of my logic and display is separate so it's easier to manage.